# Calculate the Lagrange polynomial

Tags: c

I had to write a program to calculate the Lagrange polynomial of the maddening degree of function: \$\log(x+1)+\cos(x-1)\$

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define GRADE 6

/* Funzione per costruire la successione dei nodi (xi,yi) dei punti di valutazione*/
void nodeSuccession(double* xNode, double* yNode, double* xVal){
    int i;

    printf("xNode [");
    for(i = 0; i < GRADE + 1; i++){
        xNode[i] = i; /* Array contenete le ascisse dei nodi */
        printf("%.4f, ", xNode[i]);
        yNode[i] = 0; /* Array contenete le ordinate dei nodi */
    }
    printf("\b\b]\n");

    printf("yNode [");
    for(i = 0; i < GRADE + 1; i++){
        yNode[i] = (log(xNode[i] + 1)) + cos(xNode[i] - 1);
        printf("%.4f, ", yNode[i]);
    }
    printf("\b\b]\n");

    printf("xVal  [");
    for(i = 0; i < GRADE; i++){
        xVal[i] = (xNode[i] + xNode[i+1]) / 2;
        printf("%.4f, ", xVal[i]);
    }
    printf("\b\b]\n");

}
/* Funzione per costruire il polinomio di lagrange e lo valuto nei punti */
double* polynomial(double *xVal, double *xNode, double *yNode){
    int i, j, k;
    double pr, *sum = malloc(GRADE * sizeof(double));

    for(j = 0; j < GRADE; j++){
        sum[j] = 0;
        for(k = 0; k < GRADE + 1; k++){
            pr = 1;
            for(i = 0; i < GRADE + 1; i++){
                if(k != i)
                    pr = pr * ((xVal[j] - xNode[i])/(xNode[k] - xNode[i]));
            }
            sum[j] = sum[j] + yNode[k] * pr;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

/* Funzione per la valutazione dell'errore di interpolazione */
double* error(double *xVal, double *sum){

    int i;
    double *err = malloc(GRADE * sizeof(double));

    for(i = 0; i < GRADE; i++)
        err[i] = fabs(((log(xVal[i] + 1)) + cos(xVal[i] - 1)) - sum[i]);

    return err;
}


int main(void){
    int i;
    double xNode[GRADE + 1], xVal[GRADE], yNode[GRADE + 1];
    double *poly = malloc(GRADE * sizeof(double)), *err = malloc(GRADE * sizeof(double));

    system("clear");
    printf("\n===== PROGRAMMA PER IL CALCOLO DEL POLINOMIO DI LAGRANGE =====\n\n");

    nodeSuccession(xNode, yNode, xVal);
    poly = polynomial(xVal, xNode, yNode);

    printf("\npoly  [");
    for(i = 0; i < GRADE; i++)
        printf("%.4f, ", poly[i]);
    printf("\b\b]\n");

    err = error(xVal, poly);
    printf("err   [");
    for(i = 0; i < GRADE; i++)
        printf("%.4f, ", err[i]);
    printf("\b\b]\n");

    free(poly);
    free(err);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: im confused for why you are mallocing doubles when there is no need for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Consider passing in the array size rather than fixing it at 6 in the `polynomial(), nodeSuccession()` functions.

   ```
   // polynomial(xVal, xNode, yNode)
   polynomial(6, xVal, xNode, yNode)
   ```

**Minor stuff**

2. Two backspaces may not truly "back-space".  Less problematic to not print unwanted text.  Various solutions. Perhaps as below.

   ```
   const char *separator = "";
   printf("xNode [");
   for (i = 0; i < GRADE + 1; i++) {
     xNode[i] = i;
     printf("%s%.4f", separator, xNode[i]);
     yNode[i] = 0;
     separator = ", ";
   }
   printf("\n");
   ```
3. The various calls to like code suggest that a helper print function should be written.
4. For printing `double`, I find `%e` more informative than `%f`.
5. Rather than allocate to the size of the type, allocate to the size of the de-referenced pointer.  It easier to code correctly, review and maintain.  Putting the `sizeof` part first insures any integer math is done with at least `size_t` width.  Checking for a `NULL` allocation makes for robust code.

   ```
   // sum = malloc(GRADE * sizeof(double));
   sum = malloc(sizeof *sum * GRADE);
   if (sum == NULL) TBD();
   ```
6. Use `const` with the pointers to insure wider application of the function and allow optimizations the compiler may not readily recognize.

   ```
   // double* polynomial(double *xVal, double *xNode, double *yNode){
   double* polynomial(const double *xVal, const double *xNode, const double *yNode){

   // double* error(double *xVal, double *sum)
   double* error(const double *xVal, const double *sum)
   ```
7. Help convey the `double`-ness of the variable.

   ```
   // sum[j] = 0;  // This looks `int`-ish
   sum[j] = 0.0;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As a general principle, I find it annoying when programs do this:

```
system("clear");
printf("\n===== PROGRAMMA PER IL CALCOLO DEL POLINOMIO DI LAGRANGE =====\n\n");
```

The second (i.e. print) is only a minor annoyance: I've just started the program, so why do I need telling what it is?  It does mean that I need to filter out that message if I want to pipe the results to another program.

The first (i.e. clear) is much more serious.  If I want a clear screen (and assuming that the output is going to a device where that actually means something), I can do that as a user.  If I want to keep the previous results visible, the program has denied me that option.  All assuming that the system has a working "clear" command - IIRC, there are (non-POSIX) systems that don't.

This version of the program doesn't accept arguments, but when it does, then the `clear` makes it much harder to compare different invocations, because the previous results are always obliterated.

I recommend writing only the actual output to standard output, and nothing to standard error *unless the program has not performed its task* (when it should exit with a non-zero status).

And please get into the habit of checking the return value of `printf()`.  It's annoying for programs to report success when actually the file system that their output is connected to has filled up, and nothing was actually written.